# How to make as3 AnimatorFactory play more than one frame?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am attempting to animate in the timeline, and then "copy motion as as3" so that I can reuse the animation. The problem is that when I take the AS and put it into a class, it only wants to run 1 frame, and does not continue the animation. I could use some help figuring out why this only runs the one frame instead of the the full 17.

EDIT: So I figured out how to do it. For anyone else who couldn't do it, I'm posting how to make I made it work.

```
package 
{
import fl.motion.AnimatorFactory;
import fl.motion.MotionBase;
import fl.motion.Motion;
import flash.filters.*;
import flash.geom.Point;

public class CustomClass extends MovieClip
{
            // I moved vars here 
    private var __motion_tocInside_328:MotionBase;
    private var __animFactory_tocInside_328:AnimatorFactory;

    public function CornerNavBtn()
    {
        // constructor code
        clickArea.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, activateChosen);   
    }

    public function animateOutLargeCorner():void
    {
                    // I remove the if statement so I can rerun the animation.
        __motion_tocInside_328 = new Motion();
        __motion_tocInside_328.duration = 17;

        // Call overrideTargetTransform to prevent the scale, skew,
        // or rotation values from being made relative to the target
        // object's original transform.
        // __motion_tocInside_328.overrideTargetTransform();

        // The following calls to addPropertyArray assign data values
        // for each tweened property. There is one value in the Array
        // for every frame in the tween, or fewer if the last value
        // remains the same for the rest of the frames.
        __motion_tocInside_328.addPropertyArray("x", [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
        __motion_tocInside_328.addPropertyArray("y", [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
        __motion_tocInside_328.addPropertyArray("scaleX", [1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000]);
        __motion_tocInside_328.addPropertyArray("scaleY", [1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000]);
        __motion_tocInside_328.addPropertyArray("skewX", [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
        __motion_tocInside_328.addPropertyArray("skewY", [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
        __motion_tocInside_328.addPropertyArray("rotationConcat", [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
        __motion_tocInside_328.addPropertyArray("blendMode", ["normal"]);
        __motion_tocInside_328.addPropertyArray("cacheAsBitmap", [false]);
        __motion_tocInside_328.addPropertyArray("alphaMultiplier", [1.000000,0.878937,0.765625,0.660187,0.562562,0.472687,0.390625,0.316438,0.250000,0.191437,0.140625,0.097687,0.062500,0.035188,0.015625,0.003937,0.000000]);

        // This call to initFilters supplies the Motion with an Array;
        // of the fully-qualified class names of the filters in the
        // target's DisplayObject.filters list, in the same order and
        // indices.
        __motion_tocInside_328.initFilters(["flash.filters.GlowFilter"], [0], -1, -1);

        // The following calls to addFilterPropertyArray assign data;
        // values for each tweened filter's properties.
        __motion_tocInside_328.addFilterPropertyArray(0, "blurX", [6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6], -1, -1);
        __motion_tocInside_328.addFilterPropertyArray(0, "blurY", [6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6], -1, -1);
        __motion_tocInside_328.addFilterPropertyArray(0, "strength", [0.00,1.58,1.38,1.19,1.01,0.85,0.70,0.57,0.45,0.34,0.25,0.18,0.11,0.06,0.03,0.01,0.00], -1, -1);
        __motion_tocInside_328.addFilterPropertyArray(0, "knockout", [false], -1, -1);
        __motion_tocInside_328.addFilterPropertyArray(0, "inner", [false], -1, -1);
        __motion_tocInside_328.addFilterPropertyArray(0, "quality", [BitmapFilterQuality.MEDIUM], -1, -1);
        __motion_tocInside_328.addFilterPropertyArray(0, "alpha", [1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00], -1, -1);
        __motion_tocInside_328.addFilterPropertyArray(0, "color", [0xffffff,0xffffff,0xffffff,0xffffff,0xffffff,0xffffff,0xffffff,0xffffff,0xffffff,0xffffff,0xffffff,0xffffff,0xffffff,0xffffff,0xffffff,0xffffff,0xffffff], -1, -1);

        // Create an AnimatorFactory instance, which will manage;
        // targets for its corresponding Motion.
                    // this is where I changed it, I put the var declaration up top but kept the assigning here.
        __animFactory_tocInside_328 = new AnimatorFactory(__motion_tocInside_328);
        __animFactory_tocInside_328.transformationPoint = new Point(0.500000,0.500000);

        // Call the addTarget function on the AnimatorFactory
        // instance to target a DisplayObject with this Motion.
        // The second parameter is the number of times the animation
        // will play - the default value of 0 means it will loop.

        __animFactory_tocInside_328.addTarget(<instance name>, 1);
    }

}

}
```

Comment: worth noting, the animation works fine in the stand alone player, but when opening in browser or ctrl+enter, it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out. I edited my post above and am also answering it here so that future people can find it if they come across the same problem.

```
package 
{
import fl.motion.AnimatorFactory;
import fl.motion.MotionBase;
import fl.motion.Motion;
import flash.filters.*;
import flash.geom.Point;

public class CustomClass extends MovieClip
{
        // I moved vars here 
private var __motion_tocInside_328:MotionBase;
private var __animFactory_tocInside_328:AnimatorFactory;

public function CornerNavBtn()
{
    // constructor code
    clickArea.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, activateChosen);   
}

public function animateOutLargeCorner():void
{
                // I remove the if statement so I can rerun the animation.
    __motion_tocInside_328 = new Motion();
    __motion_tocInside_328.duration = 17;

    // Call overrideTargetTransform to prevent the scale, skew,
    // or rotation values from being made relative to the target
    // object's original transform.
    // __motion_tocInside_328.overrideTargetTransform();

    // The following calls to addPropertyArray assign data values
    // for each tweened property. There is one value in the Array
    // for every frame in the tween, or fewer if the last value
    // remains the same for the rest of the frames.
    __motion_tocInside_328.addPropertyArray("x", [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
    __motion_tocInside_328.addPropertyArray("y", [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
    __motion_tocInside_328.addPropertyArray("scaleX", [1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000]);
    __motion_tocInside_328.addPropertyArray("scaleY", [1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000]);
    __motion_tocInside_328.addPropertyArray("skewX", [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
    __motion_tocInside_328.addPropertyArray("skewY", [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
    __motion_tocInside_328.addPropertyArray("rotationConcat", [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
    __motion_tocInside_328.addPropertyArray("blendMode", ["normal"]);
    __motion_tocInside_328.addPropertyArray("cacheAsBitmap", [false]);
    __motion_tocInside_328.addPropertyArray("alphaMultiplier", [1.000000,0.878937,0.765625,0.660187,0.562562,0.472687,0.390625,0.316438,0.250000,0.191437,0.140625,0.097687,0.062500,0.035188,0.015625,0.003937,0.000000]);

    // This call to initFilters supplies the Motion with an Array;
    // of the fully-qualified class names of the filters in the
    // target's DisplayObject.filters list, in the same order and
    // indices.
    __motion_tocInside_328.initFilters(["flash.filters.GlowFilter"], [0], -1, -1);

    // The following calls to addFilterPropertyArray assign data;
    // values for each tweened filter's properties.
    __motion_tocInside_328.addFilterPropertyArray(0, "blurX", [6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6], -1, -1);
    __motion_tocInside_328.addFilterPropertyArray(0, "blurY", [6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6], -1, -1);
    __motion_tocInside_328.addFilterPropertyArray(0, "strength", [0.00,1.58,1.38,1.19,1.01,0.85,0.70,0.57,0.45,0.34,0.25,0.18,0.11,0.06,0.03,0.01,0.00], -1, -1);
    __motion_tocInside_328.addFilterPropertyArray(0, "knockout", [false], -1, -1);
    __motion_tocInside_328.addFilterPropertyArray(0, "inner", [false], -1, -1);
    __motion_tocInside_328.addFilterPropertyArray(0, "quality", [BitmapFilterQuality.MEDIUM], -1, -1);
    __motion_tocInside_328.addFilterPropertyArray(0, "alpha", [1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00], -1, -1);
    __motion_tocInside_328.addFilterPropertyArray(0, "color", [0xffffff,0xffffff,0xffffff,0xffffff,0xffffff,0xffffff,0xffffff,0xffffff,0xffffff,0xffffff,0xffffff,0xffffff,0xffffff,0xffffff,0xffffff,0xffffff,0xffffff], -1, -1);

    // Create an AnimatorFactory instance, which will manage;
    // targets for its corresponding Motion.
                // this is where I changed it, I put the var declaration up top but kept the assigning here.
    __animFactory_tocInside_328 = new AnimatorFactory(__motion_tocInside_328);
    __animFactory_tocInside_328.transformationPoint = new Point(0.500000,0.500000);

    // Call the addTarget function on the AnimatorFactory
    // instance to target a DisplayObject with this Motion.
    // The second parameter is the number of times the animation
    // will play - the default value of 0 means it will loop.

    __animFactory_tocInside_328.addTarget(<instance name>, 1);
}

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your last line to this:

```
    __animFactory_tocInside_328.addTarget(cornerLarge, 0);
```

Now it repeats. You had a value of "1" which means it will only play once. The 2nd parameter defaults to "0" which loops.

[Check out the documentation on this method](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/motion/AnimatorFactoryBase.html#addTarget%28%29)

Comment: whether it's set 0, 1, or 17, it only plays one frame when within a class. This is not a solution. Also, I don't want it to loop, I want it to play once.

Comment: What you might be finding is that you have several "property keyframes" that are defined but only a single "keyframe" within the "cornerLarge" movieclip. You could try defining "cornerLarge" as a Sprite, or adding in 17 frames to the "cornerLarge" timeline. Without knowing the entire structure of your timeline, this is the most helpful I can be.

Comment: After much research into other coders having similar issues, and analyzing your code (you're only changing 2 properties) I highly recommend you re-factor your code using greensock, with TimelineLite or TimelineMax (http://www.greensock.com/timelinelite/). You can do what you're trying to do in 3 lines or less, with much less of a headache.

Comment: I guess I'll have to do that. I liked using the motion editor which is why I wanted to use this method. Now I suppose animating straight from code is going to be the only way to do it.

Comment: hmm. I see that greensock requires licensing if used for per cost business apps. I'll have to use normal flash tweens to get what I want since I'm not willing to pay annual licensing. Thanks for the suggestion. I'd still like to get the animator factory to work if anyone has a suggestion, but I suppose I'll switch to just using the as3 tween class.

Comment: Fair enough; the licensing for Greensock is only for business applications that involve a financial transaction (microtransaction, purchase to use, etc.) and are a yearly fee of $150 - $1500 depending on how many teammates you have (http://www.greensock.com/club/#corporate). It's quite affordable. But I can see if it's not good for your project, and you prefer the timeline.